# universal way to crop animated GIF?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, crop, gif

I am working on a solution to crop GIF. I got it working but the size of the image increases a lot. IE, it was 500KB animated GIF but after cropping it's 8MB animated GIF.
I suspect that's because I transform it to RGB, then merge frame with previous one if GIF has a partial mode.

here is an example of how I do that:

```
    img = Image.open(file_path)
    last_frame = img.convert('RGBA')
    p = img.getpalette()
    # this method analyzes image and determines if it's in partial mode.
    mode = analyseImage(img)['mode']
    all_frames = []
    frames = ImageSequence.Iterator(img)
    for frame in frames:
        if not frame.getpalette():
            frame.putpalette(p)
        new_frame = Image.new('RGBA', img.size)
        if mode == 'partial':
            new_frame.paste(last_frame)
        new_frame.paste(frame, (0, 0), frame.convert('RGBA'))
        last_frame = new_frame.copy()
        new_frame.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
        all_frames.append(new_frame)
    return all_frames
```

and then I store it as new image using method:

```
new_image_bytes = BytesIO()
om = all_frames[0]
om.info = img.info
om.save(new_image_bytes, format='gif', optimize=True, save_all=True, append_images=all_frames[1:], duration=img.info.get('duration'), loop=img.info.get('loop'))
```

and this image is 8MB instead of 500KB

Do I miss anything obvious ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you do here is discard all compression optimizations that the original GIF might`ve had.

Let`s say there is a 2-frame GIF, the second frame of which only changes pixels outside the crop window. After being cropped it could`ve become empty (and thus small in size), but your process makes it a full copy of the first frame, ultimately leading to the bloat you describe.

Comment: hi, thank you, I realized that too, I am gonna try to develop a solution to keep gif compression optimzation but to be able to resize it.